# how to render a component according to the condition?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In two places it is necessary to display the component `Items`.
But in one place you need an additional component `Filters`, in another - not need. The `Filters` component is inside `Items`.

When I do this , it doesn't work:

```
const Items = ({ items, users, resourceUrl }) => {
  const [goods, setGoods] = useState(items);
  const [customers, SetCustomers] = useState(users);


  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ...
  };

  const changeUser = e => {
    // ...
  }

  function DisplayFilter(props) {
    const isDisplay = props.isDisplay;
    const isUsers = props.users;
    if (isDisplay == undefined) {
      return (
        <ItemsFilters changeUser={changeUser} users={isUsers} />
      )
    }
    return null;
  }



  return (
    <div>
      <DisplayFilter isDisplay={resourceUrl} users={users}/>
      {goods.map((element) => (
        <Comment
          date={element.date}
          name={element.name}
          doctor={element.user}
          text={element.text}
        />
      ))}
      <span className="btn-show_more">
        <a className="button button_large" onClick={handleSubmit} rel="next">Show more</a>
      </span>
    </div>
  )
};
```

The data transmitted is not the same.
If you remove the output of the condition and insert in `return` - `<ItemsFilters changeUser={changeUser} users={isUsers} />`, that all works. But then the filter is displayed in other places where it should not.

Comment: Good practices suggest you need to have two components, one simple and a higher order one decorating it with filter. Any edits that make this code to work are also going to make it harder to reuse and maintain. The two answers submitted just now prove my point :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
  return (
    <div>
    {props.isDisplay
                ? (
                    <ItemsFilters changeUser={changeUser} users={props.users} />
                )
            : null}
      {goods.map((element) => (
        <Comment
          date={element.date}
          name={element.name}
          doctor={element.user}
          text={element.text}
        />
      ))}
      <span className="btn-show_more">
        <a className="button button_large" onClick={handleSubmit} rel="next">Show more</a>
      </span>
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write it like this:

```
const Items = ({ items, users, resourceUrl }) => {
  const [goods, setGoods] = useState(items);
  const [customers, SetCustomers] = useState(users);


  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ...
  };

  const changeUser = e => {
    // ...
  }   

  return (
    <div>
      {resourceUrl && <ItemsFilters changeUser={changeUser} users={users} />}
      {goods.map((element) => (
        <Comment
          date={element.date}
          name={element.name}
          doctor={element.user}
          text={element.text}
        />
      ))}
      <span className="btn-show_more">
        <a className="button button_large" onClick={handleSubmit} rel="next">Show       more</a>
      </span>
    </div>
  )
};
```

This will only render the Filter element, if your condition (resourceUrl) is present.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like having my conditional statements defined explicitly and hold the component that I want to render conditionally in a variable.

`The advantage with this is that it makes the code very clear and easy to understand and most importantly, it allows me to perform more complex conditions without getting my code all messy and hard to read as is usually the case with ternary operators.`

```
const Items = ({ items, users, resourceUrl }) => {
  const [goods, setGoods] = useState(items);
  const [customers, SetCustomers] = useState(users);


  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ...
  };

  const changeUser = e => {
    // ...
  }

 let itemFilters = null;

 if(resourceUrl) {
     itemFilters = <ItemsFilters changeUser={changeUser} users={users} />
 }


  return (
    <div>
      {itemFilters}
      {goods.map((element) => (
        <Comment
          date={element.date}
          name={element.name}
          doctor={element.user}
          text={element.text}
        />
      ))}
      <span className="btn-show_more">
        <a className="button button_large" onClick={handleSubmit} rel="next">Show more</a>
      </span>
    </div>
  )
};
```